# With whom I have a common class

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can I say "common class" in the context of being in the same class with someone?

Like "with whom I have Literature as a common class?"

Comment: We share the literature class – it is one of the common course units.

Comment: No. You can say *We have **a class in common***, but it's a bit "starchy" for most contexts. Much more natural to just say *We're **in the same** class for Literature*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please avoid giving answers in comments, it is against the site rules and encourages poor answers as they bypass the voting system.

Comment: @Astralbee: As is so often the case, your complaints fall on deaf ears. I voted to ***close*** this question, so I'd hardly be likely to post a formal Answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you've voted to close then you can't think it's a valid question for the site, so why even attempt to answer it, contrary to the site rules, in comments?

Comment: You wouldn't say "Mary, with whom I have Literature as a common class." You'd say "Mary, who's in my Literature class," or "Mary, who's in the same Literature class as me."

Answer (score 1):

This is not very good English, although it is technically correct in a way. You do have a "common class", but grammatically you have a "class in common". Perhaps you "share a class". It's kind of awkward to use such formal language in most settings though, conversationally I would say that "we are in the same class". Or "we have a class together" eg. If I was talking about a cute girl at my school, "yeah, we're in the same English class" or "she's in my English class".

In regards to common class, this elicits ideas of social standing more than anything else. eg. middle class, upper class. But it would be used so rarely that it would always seem awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Not really - it isn't at all idiomatic.

If you mean to say that you attend the same class, the idiomatic way (keeping your otherwise formal style) to say this would be:

> ... with whom I share a literature class.

In a less formal structure, you could say "*we have a literature class in common*", or more informal still, "*we are in the same literature class*".

Note that in other contexts you can say something *is* a "common [x]", such as two people having a "common ancestor" - it just isn't idiomatic in your context because the expression "*...in common*" tends to be used.

Comment: I can't accept this. *We have a literature class in common* is ***much*** more "formal, literary, stylised" than *We are in the same literature class*. Admittedly, toddlers wouldn't normally talk about "literature classes" anyway, but any five-year-old is quite capable of saying ***We're in the same class*** (and virtually ***no*** five-year-old would ever say ***We have a class in common***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your have clearly not read either the question, or my answer. You've REVERSED the order of formality I suggested, and this nonsense about what five-year olds say is neither in my answer nor the question... this is clearly another example of your personal bias against my answers which, ironically, is a lot like toddler behaviour.

Comment: You wrote *In a **less formal** structure, you could say "**we have a literature class in common**"* OR ***more formal** still, "**we are in the same literature class**"*. I don't see how I could be misunderstanding that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And yet you do.